# Anaconda Environment Breaks

Tags: python, anaconda

I have anaconda with different environments setup for different projects (one for Keras, Pytorch, etc.)  I had my Pytorch environment working fine; I installed and could import all the needed packages.  When I ran the code a week later, it failed to import packages.  For example, "import torch" gave:

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I don't think I changed anything since the code worked other than the computer restarted (Windows 10).  It seems something breaks the environment.  This happened once before, and I solved it by deleting and remaking the environment, but I would prefer not to keep doing that.

I am very inexperienced with python and anaconda, so I am not sure what diagnostic information is most relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you create a new environment or install in base?

Comment: I created new environments using "conda create -n <env_name>.  I would then activate that environment, install packages in it and launch jupyter notebook.

Comment: Another update.  I tried creating a new blank environment in anaconda prompt (ran as admin), activating it, and installing pytorch.  However, I received an HTTP error installing the package.  Interestingly, I did not receive an HTTP error when installing pytorch in my base environment.

Comment: "Welcome to Windows" one might say. Feels like DLL hell (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell). I don't any other ideas beyond one in which simply incorrect DLL is loaded.

Comment: I reinstalled anaconda and am doing everything in the base environment - seems to work (so far).  I don't know what was breaking the environments.